# Adding and subtracting multiple if-else statements in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code in codeigniter similar to this that works great.

```
<?php if (a>b) echo (a-b); else echo '0'; ?>
```

Problem is, I want to add compound functions. I've tried the code below, but it won't work. I receive an error code: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)"

```
<?php echo (if (a>b) echo (a-b); else echo '0') + (if (c>d) echo (c-d); else echo '0') + (if (e>f) echo (e-f); else echo '0'); ?>
```

Comment: This code looks unnecessarilly complicated. Use ternary operators. Why are you echoing an echoed expression? Use ``.`` for concatenation. And use ``$`` for abcdef unless they are constants

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo ((a > b)?(a - b):0) + ((c > d)?(c - d):0) + ((e > f)?(e - f):0); ?>
```

Comment: A bit of explanation would add much more value to your answer. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/29524934)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't add or pass `if-else` blocks as parameters to the `echo` statement because an `if-else` code block is not an *expression*.

To concatenate and print your values in a single line, use the `?:` *ternary* operator as

```
<?php echo ($a > $b ? $a - $b : '0') . ($c > $d ? $c - $d : '0') . ($e > $f ? $e - $f : '0');  ?>
```

Since your expression is using a string literal `'0'`, I'm assuming you want to concatenate the values as string. We use the `.` operator for that instead of `+` in PHP.

Comment: <?php echo ((a>b)?(a-b):0) + ((c>d)?(c-d):0) + ((e>f)?(e-f):0); ?>

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem in the syntax. You have to use a Ternary Operator to do so.
Here is the syntax of PHP ternary operator.

```
(Condition) ? (Statement1) : (Statement2);
```